# Induction proof of contest math problem

Tags: proof-verification, contest-math

Yesterday I have created a topic regarding one interesting contest problem. In that topic I am going to give a full solution via mathematical induction. This is not a duplicate of previous so please do not mark it.

Prove that for any positive integer $n\geqslant 2$ there is a positive integer $m$ that can be written simultaneously as a sum of $2, \ 3, \dots, \ n$ squares of nonzero integers.

**My solution:** I am going to prove more exact statement:

$\forall n\geqslant 2$ $\exists m=m(n)$: $m$ can be written simultaneously as a sum of $2,3,\dots,n$ squares of natural integers. Here $m=m(n)$ - is the square of odd number, i.e. $m=(2k+1)^2$

For $n=2$ we can take $m=5^2=3^2+4^2$

Suppose for $n$ we have found $m=(2k+1)^2$ with desired properties.

Let's try to prove this for $n+1$. Since the general form of pythagorean triples are $(x^2-y^2,2xy, x^2+y^2)$ and if we put $x=k+1, \ y=k$ we get that $(2k+1, 2k^2+2k, 2k^2+2k+1)$ is also pythagorean triple, i.e. $$(2k+1)^2+(2k^2+2k)^2=(2k^2+2k+1)^2$$
If we take $m(n+1):=(2k+1)^2+(2k^2+2k)^2=m+(2k^2+2k)^2$ then it's easy to see that $m(n+1)$ is the square of odd integer and can be written as a sum of $2,3,\dots, n, n+1$ squares of nonzero integers.

We have done.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Why do you take $m$ to be the square of an odd integer?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, that looks like good work. I would personally write $m(n)$ instead of just $m$ when relating to $m(n + 1)$, but the logic is good. I like the way that you've constructed $m$ to be square itself!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have spent few hours in order to construct this solution. However, the main idea was I took from the comments of the user Lord Shark the Unknown from my previous topic.